# Within ngx-build-plus, how can I determine build configuration?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-build-plus

Using ngx-build-plus, and within a custom plugin, how can I determine what build configuration was requested from the angular cli build command-line?

If you are wondering how I'll use this, here is the use case:
I'm trying to rename the main.ts file before compiling my project based on the build configuration I choose -->  Normal build vs. a Cordova build.  The Cordova build requires a different setup for main.ts and wrapping `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` within if statements doesn't work for web so I have no option but to use 2 different main.ts files I will switch out based on build type.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but here is a simple solution.  I don't need to determine build configuration because I can simply choose different custom plugins within the command line.

### Example

When building for Cordova:

```
ng build --plugin ~webpack.cordova.js
```

Normal Build:

```
ng build --plugin ~webpack.extra.js
```